# Scipy normal pdf evaluation gives contradictory value

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy, statistics

I am trying to write down a plot showing that an unbiased estimator is not always the best estimator. Here is the code that I've written to get a good-looking picture:

```
# Set up the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Create some data
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
# Plot two normals, one centered around 0 but with large variance
ax.plot(y, norm.pdf(y, scale=3), 'k-', label=r"pdf of $\hat{\theta_1}$")
# One centered around 1 with small variance
ax.plot(y, norm.pdf(y, loc=1, scale=1), 'r--', label=r"pdf of $\hat{\theta_2}$")
ax.legend()
# Remove left, right and top axis, remove y axis labels and ticks
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', left=False, right=False, labelleft=False)
# Remove x axis ticks and labels, keep only one at x=0
ax.set_xticks([0])
ax.set_xticklabels([r"$\theta$"])
# Plot vertical line at x=0 from y=0 to the value of the first pdf
ax.axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=norm.pdf(0, scale=3), linestyle=":")
# Plot second vertical line for second normal distribution
ax.axvline(x=1, ymin=0, ymax=norm.pdf(1, loc=1, scale=1), linestyle=":")
# Remove margins so that pdfs lie on the axis
ax.margins(0)
plt.show(block=True)
```

Basically I want to plot two normal distributions, one that is centered around 0 but has large variance, and one that is centered around 1 and has small variance. Then I want to add two vertical lines. One line goes through x=0 and reaches the value of the first normal distribution at x=0, and the second goes through x=1 and reaches the value of the second normal distribution at x=1. However, these lines are much smaller, I don't know why!

[image: plot]

My only guess is that since these are continuous pdf, scipy does something weird if I evaluate them at one point.

**Imports**

I forgot to mention my imports, I include them here so that you can have a MWE

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the docs of [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html):

```
ymax : scalar, optional, default: 1
 Should be between 0 and 1, 0 being the bottom of the plot, 1 the top of the plot.
```

Your lines are defined in *data* coordinates, not axes coordinates. You need to use [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines) instead.

```
# Plot vertical line at x=0 from y=0 to the value of the first pdf
ax.vlines(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=norm.pdf(0, scale=3), linestyle=":")
# Plot second vertical line for second normal distribution
ax.vlines(x=1, ymin=0, ymax=norm.pdf(1, loc=1, scale=1), linestyle=":")
```

[image: fixed plot]

Comment: That was super dumb of me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Euler_Salter don't be too hard on yourself, we've all been there ;)

Comment: I was actually trying to use quadrature to estimate the value of the integral there... but the solution was way simpler

Comment: @Euler_Salter Yeah; you can check the y values entering the plot calls and they are the same. Even if they're wrong they should've been the same wrong. And the value should be `1/sqrt(4*pi*sigma**2)` ;)